# Modify a value inside of a nested dynamic column

Tags: mariadb

In the table (items), I have a dynamic column (attr).

I have a very simple nested dynamic column.

```
INSERT INTO items (attr) VALUES (COLUMN_CREATE('level1', COLUMN_CREATE('level2','level2_value')));
```

Which when viewed with:

```
SELECT COLUMN_JSON(attr) FROM items;
```

Returns:

> { "level1" : { "level2" : "level2_value" } }

How can I modify the "level2_value" value?

**Things I've Tried**

Example 1

```
UPDATE items SET attr=COLUMN_ADD(attr, 'level1', COLUMN_ADD(attr, 'level2', 'NEWVALUE')) WHERE id=1;
```

> Results in: { "level1" : { "level1" : {"level2" : "level2_value"},
>   "level2" : "NEWVALUE" } }

Example 2

```
UPDATE items SET attr=COLUMN_ADD(COLUMN_GET(attr, 'level1' AS CHAR), 'level2', 'NEWVALUE') WHERE id=1;
```

> Results in: { "level2" : "NEWVALUE" }

Comment: Easiest way to fix this, IMHO, is to model the data relationally and not use "dynamic columns".

Comment: I'm not looking to "fix" anything. I'm asking about HOW-TO do something.

Comment: `column_delete` followed by `column_add` with the new value?

Comment: No need to delete. The 'column_add' function is meant to overwrite an existing value. My problem is more of the correct structure of the query. I'll post some examples i've tried later.

Answer (score 1):

After MUCH trial and error... This is the structure required to modify an item nested in a dynamic column.

```
UPDATE item SET attr=COLUMN_ADD(attr, "level1", COLUMN_ADD(COLUMN_GET(attr, "level1" as blob), "level2", "NEWVALUE")) WHERE id=1;
```

Which turns;

> { "level1" : { "level2" : "level2_value" } }

INTO

> { "level1" : { "level2" : "NEWVALUE" } }